# How to add list of new items to recycler view for exisitng list without moving to top of list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement pagination for my application and I am partially successful. When I call my server I get some 6 items and I am adding those items to recyclerview. When user comes and scrolls at the last item I am making another call to server and I am fetching page 2 items and I adding new items to existing list.

Here I am able to add new items successfully. But the problem is I am calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, hence it goes to the first item after adding new items.

How can I stop it from going to the top of the list, what should I call other than `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`? Below is my code of setting adapter

```
toadlineAdapter = new ToadlineAdapter(mContext, getData());
recyclerView.setAdapter(toadlineAdapter);
toadlineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
toadlineAdapter.setClickListener(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED TO CALL `notifyDataSetChanged` RIGHT AFTER YOU SET THIS ADAPTER TO THE `recyclerView` !!!!!!!!!!!! ... also where is a code of adding of items?

Comment: ... also from `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` docs -  *If you are writing an adapter it will always be more efficient to use the more specific change events if you can. Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as **a last resort.*** .... did you even try to read it?

Answer (score -1):

No need to notify when initializing the adapter:

```
toadlineAdapter = new ToadlineAdapter(mContext, getData());
recyclerView.setAdapter(toadlineAdapter);
// remove below line
//   toadlineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
toadlineAdapter.setClickListener(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

And notify when you are adding items, for ex:

```
YOURLIST.add(YOUROBJECT);
toadlineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```